# bash: Find files and rsync but ignore in use/open files

Tags: bash, find, rsync

I have a script that finds files of certain criteria and then syncs to `/syncDir/`. I've run into an problem with the following script for files being in use at the time of processing.

```
find -type f \( -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.properties' \) -exec rsync -zarvm {} /syncDir/ \;
```

How can I enhance the script to ignore files in use/open at the time of processing?

Comment: you can use `lsof`, but it will list  all open files you should be more specific as to what type of files you don't want listed

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. While your question is interesting, this is sadly not the place to ask as Stack Overflow is a platform for programming questions. [sf] might be a better platform. You can actually find the same question already asked there: https://serverfault.com/questions/775323/ignore-files-in-use-being-written-to-when-using-rsync . I hope this comment helped you out.

Comment: You might also be interested in the use of `fuser` to check this.

Comment: Also mildly related to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296389/shell-script-if-file-is-not-being-used-condition